# Replace the second-order ODE as two first-order ODEs and use Runge-Kutta method to solve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Replace the following second-order ODE by a system of two first-order ODEs. After writing the two first-order ODEs with the proper initial conditions, compute the corresponding values by using fourth-order Runge-Kutta method for $t = 10 s$ You can take $\Delta t=1 $

$y''=\frac{10000}{100-5t}-9.8 $

$ y(0)=0 $

$ y'(0)=0 $

My work:

Write two first-order ODEs:

$ y_1'= y_2$

$ y_2'= \frac{10000}{100-5t_1}-9.8$

I am stuck at solving these equations with Runge-Kutta and not sure if $y_1' $ and $y_2'$ are correct. Can you guide me to the right direction?

Comment: It is correct, except you have a $t_1$ instead of $t$. Also, you need $y_1(0) = y'(0)$, $y_2(0) = y(0)$.

Comment: Just consider Runge-Kutta working on the _vector_ $(y_1, y_2)$ instead of a scalar.